# In Bash, what happens when you pipe several asynchronous commands to one consumer?

Tags: bash, asynchronous, parallel-processing, pipe, buffer

Consider this Bash code:

```
(cmd1 & cmd2) | consumer
```

What possible things might `consumer` see on its standard input?

1. output from `cmd1`, then output from `cmd2`?
2. lines from `cmd1` interspersed arbitrarily with lines from `cmd2`?
3. bytes from `cmd1` interspersed arbitrarily with bytes from `cmd2`?
4. something else?

Comment: `{ { sleep 1; echo one; sleep 2; echo two; } & { sleep 1; echo three; sleep 2; echo four; }; } | cat` as a quick test. Run it a few times and you should see the pairs of lines alternating.

Comment: Here's a more interesting test: `((while true; do echo line1; done) & (python -uc 'while True: print("line2")')) | less` --- on my system you'll sometimes see "line2line1" all on one line

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can expect to see randomly interleaved data, although if the lines are short it is likely that most of the time you will see whole lines interleaved.

Since the processes have their `stdout` redirected to a pipe, which is not a interactive device, it is likely that the output will be fully-buffered. Since a buffer will be written when it is full, is likely to not correspond to the end of a line, you might expect to see interleaved buffers, with intermingled lines at the end of each buffer.

[Posix System Interfaces, 2.5 Standard IO Streams](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/V2_chap02.html#tag_15_05):

> When opened, the standard error stream is not fully buffered; the standard input and standard output streams are fully buffered if and only if the stream can be determined not to refer to an interactive device.

However, there is no guarantee that the entire buffer will be written atomically to the pipe, so there may be other interleaving effects.

Here's a quick test:

```
$ (seq 100000 & seq 100000 &) | sort | uniq -c | awk '$1!=2' | wc -l
117
```

The `awk` program prints any line which did not appear twice in the combined output, which would include all intermingled lines. So in that case, about one line in a thousand was intermingled.

By the way, in `(cmd1 & cmd2)`, only `cmd1` is being run in the background. They are still asynchronous with respect to each other, though.